# What is the best way to use jsduck to document event handlers?

Tags: javascript, extjs, dom-events, jsduck

What is the best sort of jsduck header to put over a method of a class (such as a ExtJS subclass) that handles an event? Jsduck seems to support the same tags as jsdoc, but I'm not sure if the @event tag is appropriate.

Comment: Why is it not appropriate? Why are you reluctant to follow Ext's example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An event handler should be documented the same as any other method (`@method`, etc.). `@event` is tag you would use for a listenable event:

```
function Foo() {
    /**
     * Fired when a sandwich is made
     * @event sandwich-made
     * @param {my.ns.Sandwich} sandwich
     */
    this.listen('sandwich-made', this.onSandwichMade, this);
}
```

Where you document your events is subjective. You might do it like I did above if that is the only entry point to that event, or [as is shown in the JsDuck docs](https://github.com/senchalabs/jsduck/wiki/@event), when event names are actually declared, if you do add them formally with an `addEvents(events)` method.

The docs are not explicit, but presumably any `@event` tag occurring in the context of a given object will be associated with that object.

Comment: Shouldn't you use the @param tags below the events for sandwich, errors?

Answer (score 3):

The `@event` tag in both JSDuck and jsdoc-toolkit are meant for the same thing - documenting events that get fired by a class.

Although jsdoc-toolkit docs look a bit confusing on this part, saying @event ["describes an event handled by a class"](https://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagReference), which might make it look as if it's meant for documenting listeners. But looking at jsdoc-toolkit [issue log](https://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/issues/detail?id=23) we can see the feature was inspired by events in YUI, and as ExtJS is also grown out from YUI, it confirms the semantic equality of `@event` tag in both jsdoc-toolkit and JSDuck.

You however seem to be asking about event handlers - methods that are registered to handle the events fired by other classes. Like you have a `showPopup` method and you want to document that this method handles the `click` event on some button. That's the opposite of what `@event` tag is meant for.

But you really shouldn't document your event handlers in any special way - just documenting them as normal methods should be enough. It's the same as documenting which other methods call a particular method - it might be useful to provide this information sometimes, but doing it for all the methods is just silly.

**In short.** Methods and events are an interface to a class - they should get documented. Registering event handlers and calling methods is how you use the interface - that's an implementation detail, don't document it (at least not on the same level as your API documentation).